# Find substring from end to index of a delimiter in PYTHON

Tags: python, string

I have a string say `/jrfServer_domain/jrfServer_admin/HelloWorld` , now all I want is `HelloWorld` . How can I extract it from such strings ? In this case my delimiter is `/` . I'm very new to python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [**`str.rfind`**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rfind) and [**slice notation**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation):

```
In [725]: t='/jrfServer_domain/jrfServer_admin/HelloWorld'

In [726]: t[t.rfind('/')+1:]
Out[726]: 'HelloWorld'
```

Comment: what does `t[t.rfind('/')+1:]` exactly do ?

Comment: @Droider `t.rfind('/')` finds the right-most index of `'/'` within `t`. If that index was stored in `k`, the expression would be `t[k+1:]` that is a string slice and means “take everything from the index `k+1` up to the end”.

Comment: `t.rfind('/')` returns the index of the last `/` in the list, so the index of `H` from `HelloWorld` is the `+1`, and `[foo:bar]` is returning a slice

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`str.rpartition`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition) like this

```
data = "/jrfServer_domain/jrfServer_admin/HelloWorld"
print(data.rpartition("/")[-1])
# HelloWorld
```

Comment: `print(data.rpartition("/")[-1])` would be smarter

Comment: @zmo Accessing the same element in two different ways :)

Comment: indeed, but the way I'm suggesting works whatever the `/` partitioned string is.

Comment: @zmo Thanks man :) But it will not matter for `rpartition` :)

Comment: @Droider `-1` means the least element in the result of `data.rpartition("/")`, `-2` is the last but one :)

Comment: The thing is , I have to do this in a python script , will this work ?

Comment: @Droider Indeed it will, please go ahead and use it :)

Comment: will i need to import any library for this ?

Comment: @Droider Nope, nothing is needed :)

Comment: No, `rpartition` exists for all strings. But seriously, just try it!

Comment: Getting this error :
[junit]      [exec] AttributeError: 'string' object has no attribute 'rpartition'

Comment: @Droider What is the version of Python?

Comment: How can I check it ? I'm not sure as it is a part of framework

Comment: Try `python --version` in the console

Comment: Oh, `str.rpartition` was introduced in 2
.5 only. Sorry :)

Comment: Yea i just figured it out , accepted the one with rfind

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s = '/jrfServer_domain/jrfServer_admin/HelloWorld'
>>> s.split('/')[-1]
'HelloWorld'
```

Comment: Nope, this will not be as efficient as the other methods, since it has to split the entire string based on `/`

Comment: Yes sir I get that, I think "rfind" would be more efficient.

Comment: `s.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`os.path.basename`](/jrfServer_domain/jrfServer_admin/HelloWorld):

```
>>> import os
>>> s = '/jrfServer_domain/jrfServer_admin/HelloWorld'
>>> os.path.basename(s)
'HelloWorld'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s=r'/jrfServer_domain/jrfServer_admin/HelloWorld'
>>> s.split('/')[-1]
'HelloWorld'
```

maybe you should update your delimiter in your question to "/"